# Load model or $uses array which need to be used ? while we accessing other models

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have a users controllers, I need to use photos model on that users_controllers
which can i use to access that model from the following and which is standard to use?

```
$this->loadModel('Photo');
```

or

```
var $uses =array('User','Photo');
```

Load model or $uses array which need to be used ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Anh said, it's best to access the model through relations: `$this->User->Photo->whatever()`. If the models aren't related, use `$uses` or `loadModel()`.

The models in `$uses` are loaded every time the controller is used so it's best to use it only when the other model is needed throughout the controller. If you only need it randomly then `loadModel()` is better.

Comment: There is no relationship between them

Answer (score 3):

The standard is having `Photo` and `User` model relate to each other (directly or indirectly): maybe

```
Photo belongsTo Album belongsTo User.
```

**loadModel** or **uses**: just use the one that is more convenient to you.